# How to Convert return type Task<DataView> of async to DataView in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This below method calls the RetrieveRecords method which is asynchronous and return type as Task<`DataView`> . The calling method acceptance datatype as DataView. Now I am getting an error "cannot convert from system.data.dataView to system.Task.dataView. I know the error is due to the type cast mismatch. How can I convert Task<`DataView`> to DataView. Its really required for me. I did lots of research but not able to find out the solution.

```
public DataView endresult()
{
DataView result = RetrieveRecords(sqlCommand)
}
```

asynchronous method which has return type Task<`DataView`>

```
public async Task<DataView> RetrieveRecords(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
{
    return await ExecuteDV(sqlCommand);
}

public DataView ExecuteDV(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
{

    exceptionMessage = string.Empty;
     resultType = (int)Helper.ServiceActionType.Success;
    var table = new DataTable();
    DataView dv = null;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBAccess.ConnString))
        {
            sqlCommand.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            table.Load(dr);

            if (table.Rows != null && table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dv = table.DefaultView;
            }
            else
            {
                resultType = (int)Helper.ServiceActionType.DataNotFound;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return dv;

}
```

Comment: Your underlying operation isn't asynchronous, so you shouldn't have any `Task`s in here at all.  That, or you should re-write your DB query to actually do its work asynchronously.

Comment: I dont want my db operation to be asynchronous I want the calling dv operation method to be asyn. My question is how to convert  Task<DataView> back to DataVIew in C#

Comment: Then your API is lying when it claims to be asynchronous.  It's not actually asynchronous.  And why you're trying to take a synchronous method, pretend that it's asynchronous when it's not, and then treat that asynchronous method as if its synchronous, is just beyond me.  If you have a synchronous method and you want a synchronous method, cut out all of the asynchronous stuff that you apparently don't need.

Comment: @Servy What are you talking about?  This is fine.  He wants to call his method async which is perfectly acceptable and his methods are set up correctly.  You need to mark the awaited method ExecuteDV as async to get the Task<dataView>.  Keep in mind your RetrieveRecords returns a task, not a DataView, so you must await it at some point to get the result

Comment: @MatthewFrontino No, this isn't set up correctly at all.  awaiting a non-async method doesn't magically make it asynchronous.  That won't even compile.  He has a synchronous DB query, an entirely senseless asynchronous method, and a requirement to turn his senseless asynchronous method into a synchronous one rather than just calling the synchronous method if he wants work to be done synchronously.

Comment: @Servy He needs to mark his method as async.  Other than that he is fine.  He can await his RetreiveRecords or he can hold the task and call it later.  Either way, let's be ___respectful___ to people who may not know the answer to a problem they are having.

Comment: @MatthewFrontino No, he's *not* fine.  He has serious fundamental problems that need resolving.  Just tacking `async` keywords all over the place is *not* the solution; in fact, it's the *problem* here.  Informing someone that they have a problem isn't being disrespectful at all.  I'm helping him out by informing him of a serious problem that he needs to resolve before he can continue.

Comment: I want to know I have one method which is synchronous accept DataView datatype and calling the asynchronous method which return the  datatype as Task<DataView>. Now how to map the Task<DataView> to DataView

Comment: @SanJaisy Just call the inherently synchronous method that you already have.  Don't call the asynchronous method that isn't actually asynchronous that doesn't even compile currently.  You have an inherently synchronous method.  Use that.

Comment: @Servy Having extra async keywords in your application is a bit of an exaggeration of having a "serious problem."  Regardless, I will craft a response and you can feel free to downvote me as you feel necessary.  And perhaps you should post some code that you feel is correct and see if it works for the OP so HE can understand any errors he has or has not made

Comment: @MatthewFrontino But it is a serious problem.  His asynchronous method as it is won't even compile, because awaiting a non-awaitable value isn't valid.  It's simply not a sensible method to have.  And the entire idea of wrapping a synchronous method in an asynchronous wrapper is very flawed.  If he wants to have an asynchronous database query he should be using the fundamentally asynchronous operators from his query provider. As for what he should do; he already has a working synchronous method, he wants to call it synchronously, all he needs to do is call it, and remove all of the asynchrony.

Comment: @Servy You obviously know this question is [tag:asp.net] related why did none of you bother to update the tags and remove [tag:asp-classic]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, as it currently stands, does not compile. I assume that this method signature is correct:

```
public DataView ExecuteDV(SqlCommand sqlCommand);
```

in which case, `RetrieveRecords` cannot `await` the result, so it would be:

```
public DataView RetrieveRecords(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
{
  return ExecuteDV(sqlCommand);
}
```

and your "end result" would of course be:

```
public DataView endresult()
{
  DataView result = RetrieveRecords(sqlCommand);
  return result;
}
```

On the other hand, if you are using true asynchronous methods, then `ExecuteDV` would return a `Task<DataView>`:

```
public async Task<DataView> ExecuteDVAsync(SqlCommand sqlCommand);
```

`RetrieveRecords` could be as originally written:

```
public async Task<DataView> RetrieveRecordsAsync(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
{
  return await ExecuteDVAsync(sqlCommand);
}
```

and you can then use `await` to unwrap the `DataView` from the `Task<DataView>`:

```
public async Task<DataView> endresultAsync()
{
  DataView result = await RetrieveRecordsAsync(sqlCommand);
  return result;
}
```

However, I suspect that the former is more likely, since `Fill` has not been updated with an asynchronous API.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the result of a Task, use the await keyword.

```
DataView result = await RetrieveRecords(sqlCommand)
```

Please note, however, the code as it stands is not really asynchronous at all - the method endresult is not async, and you need to mark ExecuteDV as an async method too (while also ensuring the methods inside it are actually async)

```
public async Task<DataView> ExecuteDV(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
```

Comment: I dont think we can write  DataView result = await RetrieveRecords(sqlCommand).  because return type is DataView in endresult and that method is not aysnchronous

Comment: I want to know I have one method which is synchronous accept DataView datatype and calling the asynchronous method which return the datatype as Task<DataView>. Now how to map the Task<DataView> to DataView

Answer (score -1):

Servy's comment is absolutely correct. `ExecuteDV` will NOT be asynchronous, and thus, `RetrieveRecords` will block.

Now, to answer your actual question. If you're in an asynchronous method, use

```
var dataView = await RetrieveRecords(command);
```

Otherwise, use

```
var dataView = RetrieveRecords(command).Result;
```

but note that this might block the thread until RetrieveRecords finishes execution. Blocking a thread like this might sometimes cause a deadlock. If your program freezes, you should consider this possibility. Furthermore, if you find yourself doing this alot you should ask yourself if it's possible to use async/await instead, and if it's not, ask yourself whether the method call really should be asynchronous in the first place.

And again, if you mark it as async, make sure it does asynchronous work.

Comment: i cant use Var .... If i use again i need to convert back to DataVIew. How to do that also????